# Showing some images at gallery with date

Tags: php, mysql, image-gallery

Bro, I have a php project to display some images. The image is uploaded automatically from a folder every 10 minutes interval. There is an image that goes into that folder but the image displayed is only uploaded every 1 hour, and the image that appears is the last image goes to that folder. Can you help me?

My code is:

```
`include 'connect.php';'   

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album where albumid='$aid'";    
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);           
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result))     
{    
$aimage=$row['image'];    
$aname=$row['name'];    
$adesc=$row['adesc'];    
$astatus=$row['status'];
```

Comment: You need to help others reproduce your problem. You need to share a [mcve].

Comment: You still need to give more information. The upload process happens every hour or every 10 minutes? And the code is incomplete and contains errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely provide more information, but I'm going to take a guess that the issue is with your query not having an ORDER BY statement.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_album where albumid='$aid'
```

Without knowing the column names in your table it's difficult to tell you how to fix it, but let's assume you have you have a datetime column called "uploaded_dt" that is accurately populated upon upload.

You'd change your query then to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_album WHERE albumid='$aid' ORDER BY uploaded_dt DESC
```

**ADDITIONALLY & IMPORTANTLY**

Please do not use mysql* functions.  You're opening yourself up to SQL injection problems.

Please learn about PDO before you do anything else.

Doing this query 'properly' with PDO would look like this:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare ('SELECT * FROM tbl_album WHERE albumid = :albumid ORDER BY uploaded_dt DESC');
$q->bindValue ('albumid', $aid);
$q->execute();

while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
  /* all your code here */
}
```

Now you just need to post more information about your uploading issue so we can help with that.